# "List of Lists," similar to \listoftables or \listoffigures?

Tags: macros, table-of-contents

While this may seem kind of meta, I'd like some way to create a list of lists at the beginning of a document with labels for each list. Is this easily done? Currently my project is laid out like this:

```
.
├── Portrait.pdf
├── Portrait.tex
├── img
|   ├── img01.png
|   └── ...
└── tex
    ├── sec01.tex
    ├── sec02.tex
    └── ...
```

Where the lists reside in the various section files.

Thanks!

Comment: What do there "lists" look like? Are they `enumerate`? Or `itemize`? Or [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings)? Or something else altogether?

Comment: @Werner they are in `enumerate` and `itemize` environments.

Comment: Maybe instead you should make a [list of lists that don't contain themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_lists_that_don't_contain_themselves)? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

My possible solution uses the `tocloft` facilities to generate a `\listof...` for the `enums` and `items` counters (autodefined by `\newlistof`).

In addition, `\xapptocmd` from `xpatch` writes the `\listofenums` and `\listofitems` entries by using `\addcontentsline`.

There is one backdraw so far: It's not possible to define a *title* for the `\listof...` entry.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\listofenumname}{List of enumerations}
\newcommand{\listofitemsname}{List of items}


\newlistof[section]{enums}{loe}{\listofenumname}

\newlistof[section]{items}{loi}{\listofitemsname}


\xapptocmd{\enumerate}{\refstepcounter{enums}\addcontentsline{loe}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theenums}~Enumeration}}{}{}

\xapptocmd{\enumerate}{\refstepcounter{items}\addcontentsline{loi}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theitems}~Itemize list}}{}{}



\begin{document}
\listofenums
\listofitems

\section{A section}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{enumerate}
  \item First item of second enumerate
\end{enumerate}

\section{Another section}

\begin{itemize}
  \item First item of first itemize
\end{itemize}


\end{document}
```

**Edit** Here is another solution with `xparse` and *hacking* the `enumerate`/`itemize` environments (requires `enumitem` so far) -- It allows the specify a title for the enumeration or `itemize` list, as optional argument delimited by a `(...)` pair. If there is no such pair, there's no title:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{letltxmacro} 
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\newcommand{\listofenumname}{List of enumerations}
\newcommand{\listofitemsname}{List of items}


\newlistof[section]{enums}{loe}{\listofenumname}

\newlistof[section]{items}{loi}{\listofitemsname}



\LetLtxMacro\origenumerate\enumerate
\let\origendenumerate\endenumerate

\LetLtxMacro\origitemize\itemize
\let\origenditemize\enditemize


\RenewDocumentEnvironment{enumerate}{o+d()}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \origenumerate[#1]%
  }{%
    \origenumerate%
  }%
  \refstepcounter{enums}%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \addcontentsline{loe}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theenums}~#2}%
  }{%
    % No entry to the loe
  }%
}{%
  \origendenumerate%
}   

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{itemize}{o+d()}{%
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \origitemize[#1]%
  }{%
    \origitemize%
  }%
  \refstepcounter{items}%
  \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \addcontentsline{loi}{section}{\protect\numberline{\theitems}~#2}%
  }{%
    % No entry to the loi
  }%
}{%
  \origenditemize%
}   




\begin{document}
\listofenums
\listofitems

\section{A section}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*)}](Some enum)
\item First
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\blindtext[3]

\begin{enumerate} % This won't appear in the list, since there is no `(...)` title. 
  \item First item of second enumerate
\end{enumerate}

\section{Another section}

\begin{itemize}(My first itemize)
  \item First item of first itemize
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've never done this with lists, but I've done it with drafts of textbooks in order to provide easy links from exercises to their answers in the back of the book.  For me, I used the `newfile` package, which allowed me to essentially duplicate the TOC, LOT, and LOF mechanisms for exercises.  For each exercise, I printed the exercise itself on the current page, then sent the answer to another file, `exercises.exer`; I then defined a command, `\printexercises`, which would input `exercises.exer` when it was called.  I called `\printexercises` at the end of the book.

For your case, I assume you're not redefining the lists, but instead are using standard LaTeX lists.  In that case, after each `\begin{itemize}` or whatever, put in a command like `\listoflists{List Name}`.  `\listoflists` should be define something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newfile}
\def\listoflists#1{%
    \addtostream{lol}{%
        \hbox to\linewidth{%
            #1%
            \hfil%
            \thepage%
        }%
    }%
}%
\def\printlistoflists{%
    \newinputstream{lolin}%
    \openinputfile{listoflists.lol}{lolin}%
    \section*{List of Lists}%
    \readstream{lolin}%
    \closeinputstream{lolin}%
    \newoutputstream{lol}
    \openoutputfile{listoflists.lol}{lol}
}%
\begin{document}
\printlistoflists
\begin{itemize}\listoflists{List 1}
\item First
\item Second
\end{itemize}
\newpage
\begin{itemize}\listoflists{List 2}
\item Third
\item Fourth
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

There are probably simpler ways to do it, but this has always worked very cleanly for me.  You'll need to style your list of lists, of course; the above code just throws it in the document at the left margin with a page number at the right margin.  You can also do what you like with the heading; the above code just makes it an unnumbered section.  And like TOC and friends, this is a two-pass solution.

If you don't want to manually specify the LOL entry, you'll have to redefine the `itemize` and `enumerate` environments; but since you'd have to be entering a name anyway, this is probably less work.

Comment: Nice idea, indeed!

Comment: Awesome solution, but it seems the `\input`s in the master file are messing with the way the macro works. It's simply printing:

```
lolinlistoflists.lollolin
List of Lists
lolinlolinlol listoflists.lollol
```

Comment: afischer, I can't explain that; it's compiling fine here.  I've used it with `\input`ed files before.  Are the definitions in the master file?